# An identity involving Lucas numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Let $L_n$ be the Lucas numbers, defined by $L_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n+1}$ where $F_k$ are the Fibonacci numbers.

How to prove that

$$L_{2n+1} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n + 1/2\rfloor}\frac{2n+1}{2n+1 - k}{2n+1 - k \choose k} $$

Comment: Induction?${}{}$

Answer (score 11):

The upper limit of the summation is simply $n$:$$L_{2n+1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{2n+1}{2n+1-k} {{2n+1-k}\choose{k}}.$$

Notice that as the index $k$ changes, the sum of the upper and lower numbers in the binomial coefficient remains constant at $2n+1$. In other words, ignoring for a moment the fractional coefficient, we're summing lower-left-to-upper-right diagonals in Pascal's triangle when it's written in rectangular form, as for instance shown at the top of [this web page](http://www.4dsolutions.net/ocn/Jlecture3.html). It's well known that those sums are the Fibonacci numbers: $$F_{n+1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {{n-k}\choose{k}}.$$ (It's also not hard to prove this by induction, using the recursive definition of the Fibonacci numbers and the fact that ${{n}\choose{k}} = {{n-1}\choose{k}} + {{n-1}\choose{k-1}}$.) This suggests trying to manipulate the given summation into a form recognizable as the sum of two of these diagonal sums.

This works: $$\frac{2n+1}{2n+1-k} = 1 + \frac{k}{2n+1-k}$$ and $$\frac{k}{2n+1-k} {{2n+1-k}\choose{k}} = {{2n-k}\choose{k-1}},$$ so

$
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{2n+1}{2n+1-k} {{2n+1-k}\choose{k}} &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(1 + \frac{k}{2n+1-k} \right) {{2n+1-k}\choose{k}}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left[{{2n+1-k}\choose{k}} + {{2n-k}\choose{k-1}} \right]\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {{2n+1-k}\choose{k}} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {{2n-k}\choose{k-1}}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {{2n+1-k}\choose{k}} + \sum\limits_{k=-1}^{n-1} {{2n-1-k}\choose{k}}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {{2n+1-k}\choose{k}} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {{2n-1-k}\choose{k}}\\
&= F_{2n+2} + F_{2n}\\
&=L_{2n+1}.
\end{align*}$